# Default all products are visible to all users in bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

I am using the Bugzilla v 3.6.3 and in that for all the users the products are visible to every one how to restrict to some users?

Answer (score 1):

First of all we need to set the Groups for the Products if we want for each individual product. After that set the Edit group permissions for the individual product

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "security groups" see http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/groups.html

Comment: Also you may want to upgrade to at least 3.6.12, 3.6.3 is 2 years old.